# Navbar and carousel fitting

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

Okay so here's my code at the moment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpeyx05d/2/)

Basically my goal is to get the carousel to be at same height as the navbar.

Here is link to what I imagine. [Link](http://fwrd.irontemplates.com/thepeak/)

And I want carousel to be same height and width as screen, no matter what the size is.

These things are probably easy fix for a decent developer, but not for a beginner. I have tried like for 2hrs but haven't got any solutions so far.

Any help is appreciated.

**CSS And HTML**

```css
.w-100 {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar {
        height:80px;
    }
}

#mainNav {
    background-color: grey;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: white !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgb(103, 255, 103) !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
    transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #mainNav {
        border-color: transparent;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" id="mainNav">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item active">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Muusika</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Allalaadimised</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Muusikavideod</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
    <a class="mx-auto" href="#"><img src="https://www.upload.ee/image/8361734/OdysseyLogo.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Uudised</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Allalaadimised</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.upload.ee/image/8364552/sliderimg.jpg" alt="Esimene slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.upload.ee/image/8364552/sliderimg.jpg" alt="Teine slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.upload.ee/image/8364552/sliderimg.jpg" alt="Kolmas slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Eelmine</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Järgmine</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: There's a `<>` button you can use to insert snippets. Also, two hours is not enough, especially not for a beginner. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/

Comment: Please reread and edit your question as it asking for the carousel to be the same height as the `navbar` and the full height of the viewport at the same time

Comment: Please use this... https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/
 Source : https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/
modify the background color of the navbar as transparent.

Answer (score 0):

you give `.carousel-inner` height using css `vh` unit. so it can alway match height of viewport.

try out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpeyx05d/4/)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` to achieve this using `calc` to `carousel-inner`

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: calc(100vh - 73px); // Added
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kpeyx05d/6/)

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the 
answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this :)